# how to convert json to path variable data in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have an Endpoint : `http://localhost:8080/customer/get/1`
and i want to send a json data to api in wso2esb and transform the value of id to path variable and send it to the Endpoint.
something like this:

```
{"id":"1"}
```

how can i do this?
please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build Uri-template path, with property named with prefix **uri.var.** For example named: *uri.var.myId*. and extract from JSON interesting value.
Next you can use that property in http endpoint in uri-template in brackets.

For your example, what you are looking for is something like this:

```
<property name="uri.var.myId" expression="json-eval($.id)" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<call>
   <endpoint>
      <http uri-template="http://localhost:8080/customer/get/{uri.var.myId}"/>
   </endpoint>
</call>
```

It is more precise described in [wso2esb 4.9.0 documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/HTTP+Endpoint)